# GPAC MP4Box ZLIB Error

Tags: centos, centos7, zlib, mp4box

I've been trying to get MP4Box installed on my CentOS 7 box using the following instructions:

```
...
cd extra_libs
cp -r * /usr/local/src/gpac/extra_lib
cd ..
cd gpac
chmod 755 configure
./configure
make lib
make apps
make install lib
make install
cp bin/gcc/libgpac.so /usr/lib 
install -m644 bin/gcc/libgpac.so /usr/local/lib/libgpac.so
chmod +x /usr/local/lib/libgpac.so
ldconfig
```

Everything works fine until I get to `./configure` which gives me an error:

```
./configure: line 354: gcc: command not found
error: zlib not found on system or in local libs
```

I've removed and reinstalled ZLIB and still no luck. I'm pretty new to CentOS so I'm not sure if the problem is with MP4Box or my CentOS installation. I did read that is could be a location issue, here is what I get when I run a whereis `/usr/include/zlib.h /usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that gcc was not installed. I did a `yum install gcc` and that resolved my issue.

Comment: For me, after installing gcc, `yum install zlib*` fixed the issue.